# Ajax and Brower Navigation for Back/Forward

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am using a ASP.net form with custom onclick mouse events to modify data values.  Upon clicking and updating the values, one div section of the form performs a postback.

```
onclick="__doPostBack('ctl01$phCon1$gridReports','sel1')"
```

This is working well, however when the browser BACK option is selected, the browser opens goes through the history of the DIV ajax/onclick actions prior to going back to the prior URL.

I suspect that this may be due to the doPostBack being treated as a browsing operation.  Is  there a means to perform the necessary ASP.net code events to make the page work, but not have the action stored in the browser history?

Answer (score 0):

David, why dont you try storing the action in the session and making it a part of your page load to ensure that your page is rendered correctly to reflect the scenario you want. Alternatively, you can consider a partial post back action triggered by pressing a hidden button on the page using javascript. Javascript has its own concerns if used but I am sure you will address them if you decide to progress further on that path. I remember doing it for a client in the past. Hope this helps... Andy

Comment: Novel suggestions; however I'm hoping to find a simple, native solution.  For example, GMail has tons of AJAX but it doesn't seem to interfere with going "Back".

Does anyone have insight as to how GMail ajax handles AJAX with precise control of making BACK work well?

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure your Enable history property on the script manager is set to reflect the correct setting you need as script manager has the ability to remember previous state of the page too. Hope it helps you..Andy